# Fill array with other array

Tags: java

Create two arrays A and B of size 5 and C of size 10. Accept numbers in two arrays A and B.
Fill the array C in such a way that the first five positions occupy the numbers present in array
A and rest of five positions occupy the numbers present in array B

```
import java.util.*; 
  
public class Record22_ArrayFill
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] ar1 = new int[5];
        int[] ar2 = new int[5];
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array 1:");
        for(int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++)
        {
            ar1[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array 2:");
        for(int i = 0; i < ar2.length; i++)
        {
            ar2[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j< 5; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = ar1[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j=5; j< 10; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = ar2[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    } 
}
```

Comment: This looks like an exam question?  p.s.  You'll solve your problem by fixing your for loops, at the moment you're doing double loops when you don't need to, try something like `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` do that twice, and in your second loop just add 5 to the index inside the loop for your final array.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two `for` loops; there is no need for nested loops. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/ETLaRr).

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    arr[i] = ar1[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    arr[i + 5] = ar2[i];
}
```

You can combine it into one `for` loop as well.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    arr[i] = ar1[i];
    arr[i + 5] = ar2[i];
}
```

Using [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) will be much more efficient for larger arrays, as it uses a native call. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/SFaqFU).

```
System.arraycopy(ar1, 0, arr, 0, ar1.length);
System.arraycopy(ar2, 0, arr, ar1.length, ar2.length);
```